# Is there a good way to aggregate a reportitem in a matrix?

Tags: sql, database, reporting-services

I am working on a report that has 3 categories. 2 are money, and one is a distinct count of accounts, all with totals and percentages. I have two Row Parent Groups and no column grouping. The money categories are fine but the distinct count is not matching its subtotals. Example type A is 500, type B is 600 but the subtotal is showing at 900. I understand that it is probably happening because I have a count distinct in the totals row and it is filtering out accounts that are common between type A and type B but I just need a sum of those two.

I have tried to use `inscope` in a group heading to calculate and then just reference the textbox but it is only returning the last number in the group. Instead of returning the sum of type A and type B, it is only returning the value for type B.

My expression may be off:

```
=iif(inscope("TypeIns2"),
Sum(CountDistinct(Fields!acctno.Value)), 0)
```

Comment: I meant to include that I have 2 layers of row grouping. so it would be Typegrp2 < TypeIns2<

Comment: Can you say more about the schema e.g. table (account, amount, type) and what you want e.g group by account and count distinct amount and sum amount. Some example data and what the result should be.

Comment: The grouping is by site, then by insurance group, then a second layer of insurance grouping. There is a column for expected payment, a column for what actually was paid, and then a column that counts the distinct account numbers in each group. An example of part of it would be group: site 1, insurance types: medicare hmo and medicare advantage, these are in the group Medicare, which is a subtotal in the report of the numbers in those two types.

Comment: Oddly, the financial part is great, but the issue I'm having is the count(distinct(Fields!acctno.Value)). Lets say the count is 1200 distinct accounts in traditional medicare and 900 distinct accounts in medicare hmo. The subtotal count will come to something like 1950 but should be 2100. I suppose the situation is that maybe that account number has both and has used either for different situations but I just need a sum of the 2 rows so that the subtotal calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** : Did some testing and it works (my dataset and design) but the runningvalue expression is different, aggregate is count and scope is the dataset. See below screenshots of my dataset and design and results. This is inline with what I was asking to see in the question. Could be testing table and report and data so as to not reveal your data.

[image: Table]

[image: Design]

[image: Results]

---

**Previous Answer** : Looks like you need to use the running value function. Something like

```
=RunningValue(count(distinct(Fields!acctno.Value)), Sum, "TypeIns2")
```

See documentation [Report Builder Functions - RunningValue Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function)